# Is Sencha UI and SenchaTouch only meant for web applications accessed from device or for native apps too?'

Tags: sencha-touch

As I am new to PhoneGap and SenchaTouch I want to know the basic information . I understand that sencha Touch is only for web applications accessed from device. I am correct Please clarify my doubt that is 'Is Sencha UI and SenchaTouch only meant for web applications accessed from device or for native apps too?'

Thank you
Lakshmi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha touch is a web toolkit, provides API to create interface looks similar to Native UI. But, however it is still a web application with a native look. However, if you want to crate the native packaging (application build) and if you want to access the device hardware features like camera, sensor then you can go for PhoneGap. PhoneGap can warp the HTML and JavaScript code and helps you to generate native builds for each platforms.